# Character entities in PHP and SVG

Tags: php, svg, character-entities

For my HTML content I have been using `htmlentities($instring,ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML401,"UTF-8",false)` to replace certain characters with HTML entities. However, I also serve SVG content, and some of the entities are not understood, such as `&hellip;`. Is there a special PHP function for character entities in SVG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ENT_XML1` instead of `ENT_HTML401`. SVG uses XML:

```
htmlentities($instring,ENT_QUOTES|ENT_XML1,"UTF-8",false)
```