# Mathematical symbols rendering SVG unviewable

Tags: php, html, svg

I am trying to display subtraction of 2 numbers with the subtraction symbol `&minus;` to no success. It works when i simple use `-` but that is not how a subtraction symbol should look like. I've tried with `&mdash;, &divide;, &multiply;` with no success. Is there a way to display these symbols in SVG within the `<text>` tag?

```
echo '<text x="165" y="'.$y_axis.'" font-size="30"
     font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
     fill="rgb(93, 130, 255)">
     &minus;</text>';
```

Comment: As a [unicode character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm) perhaps. &minus; is a HTML thing as are all the other entities.

Comment: yes i'm beginning to think so too but what are the unicode characters acceptable in SVG?

Comment: All of them that you have a font for.

Comment: Given that the `-` is actually the minus symbol and part of the basic set of universal characters, I see no reason why you do not simply put `-` in the svg area. Its not like you are trying to do something like ™ or © which requires something above basic ascii.

Comment: Yes i agree with you as a laymen approach but apparently it is not an acceptable symbol in a 'Math' environment. It just amazes me how these people can see the difference...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Character entities in PHP and SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474432/character-entities-in-php-and-svg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `HTML Entity (named): &minus;` it must be in `HTML Entity (HEX): &#x2212;`. The same format applies to other symbols.